# Count and a Sum in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so i have a query that works which gives the sum cost:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) AS 'Sum of Cost', 
MONTH(startDateTime) AS Month,
MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(startDateTime), '%m')) month_name
FROM Event
GROUP BY Month;
```

The other thing I wanted to add to this query was the amount of times that an event took place in each month as their are a few months that have events on the same days thus affecting the total sum of the events.

Comment: group by is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due you're grouping by month, you can use both, SUM and COUNT in the same sentence.

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) AS 'Sum of Cost', 
       MONTH(startDateTime) AS Month,
       MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(MONTH(startDateTime), '%m')) month_name,
       COUNT(*) as NumEvents
FROM Event
GROUP BY MONTH(startDateTime);
```

Comment: there is a logical order to follow.. group by an alias won't work

Comment: in sql server we do select datepart(month,getdate())

Answer (score 0):

first off update your group by.. accordingly to Logical order

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) AS 'Sum of Cost', MONTH(startDateTime) AS Month
FROM Event
GROUP BY  MONTH(startDateTime);
```

Comment: Your query is identical to the one in the question.. This answer is invalid.

Comment: you blind? check the group by

Comment: This just gives me the exact same to what i already had? The 'Month' has been renamed by the 
    MONTH(startDateTime) AS Month

Comment: wait kids.. ill update my query.. i thought the initial problem was the group by since that's wrong.

Comment: The group by is not wrong? as is above after the AS section

Comment: check the logical order of a query mate, http://blog.aajtech.com/blog/sql-programming-understanding-the-logical-order-of-operations-in-select-statements/  

FROM Clause
ON
OUTER
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP

Comment: how can you Group by an alias where SELECT has not been read yet.

Comment: at least giving me points for correcting your group by. cheers. @lazerkid